# How to change image repeat pattern in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html2canvas

**I am trying to create many different image repeat pattern**. I used the following code for the repeat pattern. The code is working fine for regular patterns but ***I need many different sets of the pattern as the image is shown below.***

[image]

***OR Like below...***

[image]

***But with the below code I have this pattern only that is here ....***[image]

```
<div style="width: 675px;height:675px;overflow: hidden;"><canvas id="cc" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas></div>

<script>
    drawPattern(img, current_size);
    function drawPattern(img, size) {
         var canvas = document.getElementById('cc');
         
         var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
             tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
    
         tempCanvas.width = size;
         tempCanvas.height = size;
         tCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, size, size);
    
         // use getContext to use the canvas for drawing
         var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(tempCanvas, 'repeat');
         
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
         ctx.fill();
    
    }

</script>
```

Please help in this that how I can get that different patterns. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can change how the image is drawn  and thus the pattern using `setTransform`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform and associated functions. For example to mirror pattern horizontally draw the image twice, once normally and once mirrored along x. Also increase the canvas size to fit the two images, eg   `var w = size;cc.width = w*2; cc.height = w; tCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, w); tCtx.setTransform(-1,0,0,1,w*2,0); tCtx.drawImage(img, w* 2, 0, w, w); var pat = tCtx.createPattern(cc,"repeat")` to use `ctx.fillStyle = pat`

Comment: Excellent, that really helped. Thanks! @Blindman67

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are infinite patterns you can accomplish. So it's difficult to tell you all the code that you are looking for. You should research a lot of tecniques and "steal" ideas for yourself.

From what I saw you are using JavaScript to perform this patterns, but there are other ways to accomplish this. You can simply use `HTML` and `CSS` for example. Like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("image.png");
            background-repeat: repeat-y;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The background-repeat Property</h1>
    <p>Here, the background image is repeated only vertically.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, the `background-repeat` property can have the following values:

```
background-repeat: repeat|repeat-x|repeat-y|no-repeat|initial|inherit;
```

For last there are more `CSS` properties you can use to perform different background patterns, like:

```
background-position: center; /* Center the image */
background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
```

`HTML` and `CSS` documentation:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp